# How to prevent abort by pressing ESC key (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, escaping, key, keycode

I would like to prompt a string. My additional need is to not escape by pressing the ENTER or ESC key.
With this method ENTER works (doesn't escape):

```
var f1 = '';
while (f1.length < 1) {
  f1 = prompt('Please give a value of the string!');
}
```

How can I reach, that this script doesn't escape by pressing ESC either?
Thanks,
hazazs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt` returns `null` when you click ESC button. You need to check null also in while

```
while (f1 == null || f1.length < 1)
```

Or simply

```
while (!f1)
```

Use this one:

```
var f1 = '';
while (!f1) {
     f1 = prompt('Please give a value of the string!');
}
```

> Note: As Cancel and ESC both returns null, you will not be able to
>   Cancel it though.

Comment: It works without var f1 = ''; as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! so is it your answer ? I f yes, do accept it.